# Sitecore Form Condition to check field should not be empty

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am trying to check if the field is not empty then navigate to next page.

Please let me know how can we achieve using Sitecore Form condition.
Kindly refer to the image attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the field mandatory and hide the submit button using the condition. That way you can ensure the user will not be able to go to the next page with empty message field value.

Follow the below steps to achieve your requirements.

1. Create a new Sitecore Form
2. Drag and Drop `Page` element from the Form element section.
3. Again drag and drop `Page` element and name it "ConfirmationPage"
4. Select the first page and prepare a form structure like below

   - Place `Section` and under the section add your field called `Message` as a Multiline line text field.
   - Change the label to `Message`.
   - If you want the Message filed as Mandatory you can mark it as mandatory.

   [image]
5. Add another `Section` and then add `Submit button` to the section.
6. Click the `Submit button` and change the Lable and Field name as per your need. Now click the `Edit conditions` button and add the condition

   [image]

   Submit button:
   [image]

Alos, you can control the `Submit` button to be displayed on `Section` level like if the `Message` field is Empty then Submit button is hidden and once the user interacts with it it will come up.

[image]

Hope it helps!